# RAM shows 988 MB instead of 3 GB

Tags: memory

My previous ram was 1 GB with 32 bit OS 7, processor 2.70 GHz. Yesterday I Installed a 2 GB additional ram & 64 bit windows 7, but it still shows 'Installed memory 3.00 GB (988 MB usable!)". In task manager resource monitor shows- Hardware Reserved 2084 MB, In Use 831 MB, Standby 150 MB, Free 2 MB.
Can anyone tell me why & how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have any integrated graphics?

Comment: I think no. I am a simple user, know very little about hardware.
It shows only Intel(R) G41 Express Chipset WDDM 1.1 in my Display adapters..

Comment: Look in the BIOS, maybe you can change the setting there. If that doesn't work, try changing (updating or downgrading) your drivers, sometimes they can bug the memory available.

Comment: post more details about the used hardware (motherboard)

Comment: Found nothing to change in BIOS @Lenniey

Comment: @magicandre1981
Windows 7 Ultimate
Version 6.1.7600 Build 7600
Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Model G41M-Combo
System Type x64-based PC
Processor Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU E5400 @ 2.70GHz, 2700 Mhz,
BIOS Version/Date Award Software International, Inc. F1, 5/20/2010
SMBIOS Version 2.4
Windows Directory C:\Windows
System Directory C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 3.00 GB
Total Physical Memory 988 MB
Available Physical Memory 349 MB
Total Virtual Memory 1.96 GB
Available Virtual Memory 733 MB
Page File Space 1.00 GB

Comment: update to BIOS version F3, and after doing it,l lod the default BIOS setting.s Now look if Windows detects the complete 3GB. Also check the msconfig suggestions

Comment: How is the RAM laid out? Have you put the 2GB in slot 1?

Comment: Tried both; firstly the 2GB was in slot 2 (the 1GB was in slot 1), then I chenged them, nothing happened :(

Comment: have you made the BIOS update and have you loaded the default settings?

Answer (score 1):

don't know how it would happen accidently, but it is possible to limit
how much ram the computer uses in msconfig.exe.
type in msconfig.exe in your start\search window and hit enter.
under the boot tab, click the advanced button and then look for
the maximum memory setting in the upper right hand corner. make sure
that it is set to 0 (all available physical memory). I would check
there first.

Comment: It's the most common solution of the problem on internet. But in my case it simply doesn't work :(

Comment: is your virtual memory turned off?  goto control panel, set to large icons, click system, on the left side of the page, click advanced.  under advanced, the 1st box is performance. click settings.  under performance options, click advanced again. there is an option to change the size of your paging file(virtual memory). mine for example is set to a minimum of 6000 mb and will expand to 10000 mb as necessary.